# What .htaccess RewriteRule do I need to redirect correctly when no page is specified in the URL?

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, apache2, node.js

In my directory

http://tanguay.info/webtech

I have the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:49900/home [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:49900/$1 [P,L]
```

It routes correctly if I provide a page (a node app with .eps files)

http://tanguay.info/webtech/home

But if I don't provide a page:

http://tanguay.info/webtech

It gives this error:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tanguay2/public_html/n49900_dpndev/systemPages/index.html.var.ejs'`

It seems to be going to `index.html.var.ejs` instead of the `http://127.0.0.1:49900/home` that I specified, but I don't know where it is getting this `index.html.var` information.

How do I get it to correctly link to `http://tanguay.info:49900` if I provide no page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index.html.var` maybe set as your `DirectoryIndex`. In which case, mod_dir issues an internal subrequest for this document. (Does this file exist?)

How you match this with mod_rewrite can depend on your Apache version (2.2 vs 2.4). In Apache 2.2 mod_dir executes *before* mod_rewrite. The order reversed in 2.4.

In Apache 2.4 a `RewriteRule` *pattern* of `^$` should be sufficient (since it is processed before mod_dir issues the subrequest). If the directory index document does not exist then this should also work on Apache 2.2. However, to catch both possibilities then check for both...

For example, change your first `RewriteRule` to read:

```
RewriteRule ^(index\.html\.var)?$ http://127.0.0.1:49900/home [P,L]
```

Or, you could disable the `DirectoryIndex` (if it's not being used) at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
```

Comment: `DirectoryIndex disabled` fixed it, thanks.